# Remain Cursor postion inside EditText android

Tags: android-edittext, android-cursor, backspace

I have one backspace image button to delete one character after cursor inside an Editext field

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/backspace"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/result"/>
```

And this is code

```
EditText resultEditText = (EditText)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.result);

int curPostion;

curPostion = resultEditText.getSelectionEnd();

//getting the selected Text
SpannableStringBuilder selectedStr = new SpannableStringBuilder(resultEditText.getText());

//replacing the selected text with empty String
selectedStr.replace(curPostion - 1, curPostion, "");
resultEditText.setSelection(curPostion);

//Set new string
resultEditText.setText(selectedStr);
```

My problem is when I press the backspace button, one character is deleted successfully, but the cursor immediately come back to the first postion of the EditText.

***How to remain cursor to the position after deleting a character?.***

I'm really appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the solution, just delcare a new variable to store the new cursor postion then setSelection().

In detail

```
EditText resultEditText = (EditText)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.result);

int curPostion;

curPostion = resultEditText.getSelectionEnd();

//getting the selected Text
SpannableStringBuilder selectedStr = new SpannableStringBuilder(resultEditText.getText());

//replacing the selected text with empty String
selectedStr.replace(curPostion - 1, curPostion, "");

//Store postition
int afterDelPosition = curPostion - 1;
```

//Set new string
    resultEditText.setText(selectedStr);

```
//This will remain the cursor position
resultEditText.setSelection(afterDelPosition);
```

I hope this will be helpfull.